# Importing Dump (.dmp) file into mysql

Tags: database, oracle, mysql

Can I import .dmp file created from oracle (8i) into MySql database? I tried importing the dump file directly using mysql workbench, but showing some error which I am mentioning below.

---

```
Creating schema newschema

10:49:15 Restoring G:\dmp\pass.dmp

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\acer\appdata\local\temp\tmpliqb6y.cnf"  --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=newschema < "G:\\dmp\\xyz.dmp"

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
```

---

How to solve this?

Comment: can you post the first few lines of the .dmp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you probably can't.

An Oracle export is a proprietary, undocumented files format.  It can, realistically, only be read by the Oracle import utility.  There may be some third party tools that may have reverse engineered the file format, but I'm not aware of any that would import into MySQL.

If you import the data into a local Oracle database, it becomes much easier to transfer it into a MySQL database.  Any ETL tool can do so, you can write an application to move the data, you can connect from Oracle to MySQL to push the data, you can extract the DDL and DML from the Oracle database, etc.

Comment: Thank you Justin. I have tried extracting DDL and DML and running in MySql. Now since the number of tables is too much it is cumbersome to repeatedly extract the DDL and run in MySql. Connecting Oracle to MySql looks like a more convenient way. Can you please tell me how to connect from Oracle to MySql?

Comment: is there a free ETL tool available in the net?